# python module and imports

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, python-import

If this is my directory tree

```
temp
├── __init__.py
└── __main__.py

0 directories, 2 files
```

And I have the following code in `__init__.py` and in `__main__.py`

### __init__.py

```
"""Initializes the module"""

CONSTANT = 1
sys.exit("what is happening here")
```

### __main__.py

```
# from . import CONSTANT
# from temp import CONSTANT
if __name__ == "__main__":

    print "This should never run"
```

I am getting two problems here that I am trying to figure out

On running `python .` in the `temp` directory I get the output
`This should never run`,  shouldn't the module be initialized first with the `__init__.py` file resulting in the abort?

Second how do I go about doing imports in python modules?  Neither of the two options I have mentioned above works.  I can neither do `from . import CONSTANT` nor `from temp import CONSTANT` in the code above.  What is the right way to do relative imports?

I am running this on Python 2.7.5,  apologies if this has already been asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be running it from out of the `temp` directory. If `someDir` contains your `temp` directory, then:

```
someDir $ python -m temp   #someDir/temp/__init__.py is your file.
```

---

> On running python . in the temp directory I get the output This should never run, shouldn't the module be initialized first with the **init**.py file resulting in the abort?

If you run it from outside, `__init__.py` will be called. And `sys.exit` will be called too.

---

> Second how do I go about doing imports in python modules? Neither of the two options I have mentioned above works. I can neither do from . import CONSTANT nor from temp import CONSTANT in the code above. What is the right way to do relative imports?

You are doing it just fine. Just import sys in your `__init__.py` file. And fix the spelling of `CONSTANT`.

---

> Also why do I need the -m flag? Isn't it ok to just do python temp from the parent directory of temp?

You need the `-m` flag to tell that you are using packages. If you dont use it you wont be able to do relative imports.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  Should I be doing `from . import CONSTANT` or `from temp import CONSTANT`?  What is the better way to do it?

Comment: Also why do I need the `-m` flag?  Isn't it ok to just do `python temp` from the parent directory of temp?

Comment: Both are fine (when using `-m`). I personally, prefer the absolute version. I'll answer your other question inline.

Answer (score 1):

You are running *inside* `temp`; this is not considered a package and `__init__.py` is not loaded. Only if the *parent* of the current directory is on the module loading path and you explicitly load `temp` as a module, is `__init__.py` loaded.

Because `temp` is *not a package* you can't use relative imports here. Instead, every Python file inside of the directory is considered a top-level module all by themselves.

You'd have move to the parent of the `temp` directory, then run:

```
python -m temp
```

for Python to import `temp` as a package and then run the `__main__` module in that package.

Answer (score 1):

When you tell Python to run a directory, **Python does not treat the directory as a package**. Instead, Python [adds that directory to `sys.path` and runs its `__main__.py`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#interface-options). `__init__.py` is not executed, and relative imports will not view the directory as a package.

If you want to run a package's `__main__.py` and treat it as part of the package, with `__init__.py` executed and all, go to the directory containing the package and run

```
python -m packagename
```